# How to create custom tag helper in asp.net core mvc 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Im really confused here, i have done every thing , bit by bit according to this link : [CreateCustomTagHelper](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/22/creating-custom-mvc-6-tag-helpers.aspx) , but so far i could not accomplish it. I use the exact code from the link, but the main problem is that i cant reference the tag helper in razor view, i use the this line of code for referencing but it does not work : 
`@addTagHelper "*, TestTagHelper.CustomTagHelpers.ProgressBarTagHelper"` ,

i get this error :

```
Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly 'TestTagHelper.CustomTagHelpers.ProgressBarTagHelper'. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'TestTagHelper.CustomTagHelpers.ProgressBarTagHelper' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@addTagHelper "*, TestTagHelper.CustomTagHelpers.ProgressBarTagHelper"
```

Comment: I think its not able to locate `TestTagHelper.CustomTagHelpers.ProgressBarTagHelper`. Make sure you added the `project reference` in current project, if the file is not in the the same project.

Comment: It is the current project,i'm afraid that's not the case .both the razor cshtml that i want to use the tag helper that the tag helper implementation are in a unique project.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear about it. You have to enter the assembly name there, not the full qualified name of your tag helper.

Assuming from your comments that it's in the same folder as the web application, I guess your web application project name is `TestTagHelper` so you need to use `@addTagHelper "*, TestTagHelper"`.

Comment: I have already tested all combinations ,@addTagHelper "*, TestTagHelper" . but again i get the same error. i know i did some thing wrong , but so far i could not resolve it.

Comment: What's the name of your project which contains the `ProgressBarTagHelper`?

Comment: I made another project , i copy the tag helper there, and its very strange every thing just worked. i dont what is wrong with my previous project, but in the new project its ok and its running.

Comment: Okay, but just to be sure. Name of your web project was `TestTagHelper` right? Did you build it before just in case?

Comment: i made a bad mistake, my project in under a name with two parts, and i just mention the first part. this is very bad, i am so sorry and thank you for your consideration.

Comment: @EhsanElhampour: Add your solution or whatever worked as an answer and check it as accepted so the question doesn't appear in the unanswered tab and future readers can see the solution